# Should I or must I use API key restrictions for a google api key?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-places-api

Using the GooglePlaces pod in an iOS app, I'm confused about how/whether to restrict the API key.  The Google UI is confusing.  First, on the cloud dashboard (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=myProjectId)...

[image]

I can't find any explanation about what "PRIVATE" means. Hovering over the "?" provides a tooltip that says, merely, "You've been granted access to this API".

On the credentials tab of the dashboard, that same key is decorated with a warning, and a tooltip that says "This API key is unrestricted. To prevent unauthorized use and quota theft, restrict your key...".  Scary. OK, I'll do it.

[image]

After lot's of UI and help articles about adding restrictions, I end up restricting to iOS apps, and restricting to places API, (also tried combos with Maps API). This got REQUEST_DENIED under every circumstance.

Then I found this, https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied, a "Google Maps Platform" FAQ answering the question, "Why do I keep receiving status; REQUEST_DENIED?  At the bottom:

> API keys with Android or iOS restrictions are not supported. Please
>   use a generic (unrestricted) API key, or a key with browser or server
>   restrictions.

This is the first and only reference to this exception I see anywhere in numerous docs and help articles.

So, Google, leave my key unrestricted?  What do you really want Google (and please don't send a robot army to kill me)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is listed here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices 1.) you do NOT have to restrict a key. However if you let an unrestricted key get leaked you DO have to pay the bill for its usage! 2.) The link I posted will tell you how to restrict your key. Personally I strongly recommend setting up a budget so you'll get notified if there is a sudden spike in your key being used.

I believe the "Private" question is a different subject from protecting your api key.